# Why isn't this code hitting a race condition?

Tags: multithreading, go, race-condition, goroutine

I have this go code which walks a directory file tree and produces MD5 hashes of every file in it and writes the result in an output file.

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "sync"
)

func main() {

    filePath := os.Args[1]
    output := os.Args[2]
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

    err := filepath.Walk(filePath, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if !info.IsDir() {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(path string) {
                md5Sum, _ := md5File(path)
                if err := writeToFile(path, md5Sum, output); err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
                wg.Done()
            }(path)
        }
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func md5File(filePath string) (string, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    hash := md5.New()
    if _, err := io.Copy(hash, file); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    checksum := hash.Sum(nil)

    return string(hex.EncodeToString(checksum)), nil
}

func writeToFile(filePath, md5sum, output string) error {

    file, err := os.OpenFile(output, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE, 0755)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer file.Close()

    file.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%s %s\n", md5sum, filePath))

    return file.Sync()
}
```

From my understanding it is bound to run into a race condition sometime upon writing to the output file but it never does. I mean I have executed this code countless times never facing any issues. It even produces the same result every time.

Why is that? Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:** When I say it is bound to face a race condition I mean when running multiple goroutines it is possible for more than one goroutine to want to write to file at the same time.

Comment: *"From my understanding it is bound to run into a race condition sometime ..."* - can you please explain your understanding in more detail, i.e. where exactly you see a race conditions which should happen in what circumstances and how should the result look like if the race happened? So far it is only that you expect some race without telling any details about it and then expect others to explain why the thing you did not explain did not happen.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have added more detail to the question.

Comment: Care must be taken: not all file systems are POSIX-compatible. Best would be to synchronize / serialize the writes (appends) to the file. It's a waste to open / close it every time. Open it once, and close it where you're done with all your files.

Comment: @icza I understand. I purposefully wanted to force a race condition just for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I say it is bound to face a race condition I mean when running multiple goroutines it is possible for more than one goroutine to want to write to file at the same time.

It is not a problem to open a file multiple times. And since you explicitly use `O_APPEND` the writes don't interact badly with each other. To cite 
 from [man open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html):

> **O_APPEND** ...
>   Before each write(2), the file offset is positioned at the end of the file, as if with lseek(2). The **modification of the file offset and the write operation are performed as a single atomic step**.

Comment: Well, removing the `O_APPEND` flag made no difference. Maybe a little slower but the result is the same.

Comment: @HamedMomeni: if you remove `O_APPEND` you'll get a file which always contains only a single md5sum since every new `open+write` will write at the beginning of the file. Maybe you should be more clear what exactly you expect as result of the race.

Comment: Well I expect to some lines to be mingled and also the total number of lines should be inconsistent. But it is not the case with this code.

Comment: And as for why I'm not getting a single line output, I moved file opening outside the write function so as not to open the file anew for every call.

Comment: @HamedMomeni: *"I moved file opening outside the write function so as not to open the file anew for every call."* - Which is a totally different thing than what you did in your question. Because in this case you have the shared file offset in the OS kernel - which again does not produce a race. A race could happen if you do the open in the go routine, seek to the end of the file and then write. Because only then you have a local file offset which can get affected by the race between seeking and writing.

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to get it now. Thanks for the explanation. As you have said if I open the file in every goroutine and skip the `O_APPEND` flag I get the race condition I'm looking for. Well the OS does a very good job to protect us from our own stupidity.